# How to refresh Twitter feed widget automatically with a custom script

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to create a twitter feed for my office dashboard. I've bascially got the twitter news feed, but I want it to refresh automatically when there are new tweets, instead of clicking on the "View [x] new Tweets".

Is there a way to locally load in JS and CSS so I can trigger the refresh automatically when new tweets are avaialalbe. I could also use CSS to hide certain elements that I didn't want to show i.e "Who to follow" sidebar.

```
var tweets = $(".new-tweets-bar.js-new-tweets-bar").getAttribute("data-item-count");

if( tweets ) {
  window.reload();
};
```

Thank you.

Comment: For starters, you can't `parseInt` a jQuery object. You'd want to get its text value.

Comment: You will want to make an [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call

Comment: @isherwood oh okay, so the parseInt part is not required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set up a timer in JavaScript to see when that View [x] new Tweets element is updated and then use window.reload();

Comment: Hello Chris. Yes that was my initial idea, however I'm unsure if I can bring in the local JS again after page reload to start the timer again.

Comment: $.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: "script"
});

This will add a JavaScript file dynamically.